# Example of Random Binary Tree?

Tags: trees

I'm trying to understand what a random binary tree is. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree):

> Two different distributions are commonly used: binary trees formed by
>   inserting nodes one at a time according to a random permutation, and
>   binary trees chosen from a uniform discrete distribution...

If I start with a root and then append nodes randomly with no consideration to depth. Would that be considered a random binary tree? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "with a random leaf as parent"? What is logic behind adding a single node? For example, node adding like in a binary search tree.

Comment: I actually just meant randomly appending to the bottom rather than doing any sort of inserts. I shouldn't have said leaf. @fade2black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random binary tree is any tree that is generated by any random process.  So, yes.  You have described a random process that generates a binary tree; you can describe the result as a random binary tree.

At a technical level, if you have any random variable whose values are binary trees, it would be reasonable to call that a "random binary tree".

Wikipedia is saying that there are two random processes that are particularly commonly considered.  But those aren't the only possibilities.  You've described a third possibility, and that's also valid.